# SQL: LIKE and " ' "

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have to get this entry: "**l\'arbre**".

Here is one of the various requests I've made:

```
SELECT id,nom FROM serie WHERE nom LIKE "%l\'%"
```

but it doesn't work (0 rows returned).

But this works:

```
SELECT id,nom FROM serie WHERE nom LIKE "%\'%"
```

Does anyone have an idea of the problem?

Comment: If this from PHP? Or in MySQL workbench etc?

Comment: Although people are saying the % wildcard is 0 or more characters, this has never been the case for me. I've never gotten a % to match 0 characters at the beginning or end of a line. Apparently there is something I'm missing as well.

Comment: Does the field contain `"l'ambre"` or `"l\'ambre"` ?

Comment: @animuson: Have you tried a query with `field LIKE "%a%"` ? Just try it and you 'll see that it returns words that start from `a` too.

Comment: Can't repro, the first select works with a text column containing `l'arbre`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. @ gbn: it's mySQL workbench. @ animuson: I tried but % is 0 too. @ Mat: I've **l\'arbre** in my database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
nom LIKE "%l\\\\'%"
```

Comment: Is that double or triple escaping?

Answer (score 1):

If the DB has the value "**l\'arbre**", `"%l\'%"` will not work since the `\` is an escape character, so `l\'` translates to `l'` which does not appear in the DB value.

Try `LIKE "%\\\\\'%"`

The first `\\\\` means one backslash, and the `\'` means the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `'l\'arbre'` in the database, you need to change the query to `... LIKE "%l\\'%"`. In your current query, the backslash is interpreted as being a string escape character that escapes the apostrophe. You need it to be interpreted as a literal backslash, which means you need to escape it with a backslash.